# ssl/https for self-hosted WCF Services, WCF Data Services (OData) and Web Pages in a C# Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, https, wcf-data-services

I have a Windows Service application written in C# which performs a number of tasks in the background. As a side-feature, the application offers interfaces for UI clients to connect to (currently a WPF client application). This is mainly WCF Data Services (OData) and WCF services for now, but may also include serving web pages (through embedding ASP.NET) so a browser could be used to access the service.

All of this works pretty well, with self-hosted services through ServiceHost+WSHttpBinding and DataServiceHost+WebHttpBinding, which is all setup in code (since it is somewhat dynamic/flexible).

Now I started to look into authentication and worked myself through setting up a basic authentication with a custom name/password validator through MessageCredentialType.UserName, UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom, etc. Now clients need to provide correct username/password which is validated against an application specific user list. This also works well, with something like

```
webHttpBinding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
webHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

serviceHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
serviceHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new UserRepositoryPasswordValidator { UserRepository = UserRepository };

serviceHost.Authorization.PrincipalPermissionMode = PrincipalPermissionMode.Custom;
```

However, as I understand, without any kind of transport security, username/password as well as any data is being transmitted in plain text between client ans service, which is not desirable. I have therefore tried to find a way to use a secured/encrypted communication. This sounds like ssl/https would be the way to go.

I went through a number of articles to find out how to do this, but find the approach overly complicated and confusing. My application obviously does not use IIS or another web server, so many articles and posts do not seem to apply to my scenario. 
Also, the application in question should be deployed/installed onto different target machines and "just run" without the need to tweak any operating system aspects. I was highly confused to see that using ssl/https requires to run netsh commands to register the certificate with the port, etc. Why is this so complicated?

I can accept that the certificate used for ssl/https would not be a highly trusted one, since it would be impractical to create a new certificate for every target machine my software gets installed on (most of which I do not even control or ever see).

Does anyone have instructions about a good acceptable strategy to get my current C# Windows Service with self-hosted WCF/WCF Data Services to use ssl/https without too much trouble and without complicating the installation process of my app?

J.-